# Swap text block order for mobile view on Squarespace

Tags: css, mobile, position, block, squarespace

I've already asked this on Squarespace but have received ZERO help and I'm getting desperate (sad face). So I'm hoping people here might be a little more friendly :D

I'm wondering if anyone would be kind enough (pretty please) to write a code for me similar to the code Aarnaa got in the [link here](https://answers.squarespace.com/questions/136285/swap-block-order-in-mobile-view.html). I have no experience in code and have been trying my best to mash something together for almost a week now, but unfortunately have been unsuccessful!

I am creating a website for an Omani Women's charity and part of the website needs to be in Arabic and Arabic reads Right-To-Left. The problem I'm experiencing is that text blocks also have to read Right-To-Left. This looks fine on desktop, but when I view the page (link below) on mobile, it stacks it up and orders it in a way that doesn't make sense anymore (2,1,4,3,6,5).

https://sim-zuk-7r39.squarespace.com/our-objectives-a/

To solve the problem the blocks on mobile need to read Right-To-Left so that block 1 would come before block 2 (even though block 1 is on the right hand side of the page on the desktop version). Hope this makes sense?

If anyone could help me I'd be eternally grateful!

Thank you sooooo much in advance, 
Sim

Comment: I am currently writing you an example! Hold tight.

Comment: Thank you! I shall!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this class to your css...

```
[class*=sqs-col] {
    float: right !important;
}
```

and in the html change the order like this

```
<div class="col sqs-col-4 span-4">...... 2.....</div>
<div class="col sqs-col-4 span-4">...... 1.....</div>
```

to

```
<div class="col sqs-col-4 span-4">...... 1.....</div>
<div class="col sqs-col-4 span-4">...... 2.....</div>
```

---

if you only have access to the css you can try [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) with [media query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

```
@media  (max-width: 600px) {
    div#yui_3_17_2_1_1497969035108_70 .sqs-row{
      display: flex !important;
      flex-direction: column-reverse !important;
    }

}
```

adding this to your css file

Comment: Hi RenzoCC thanks for your reply! Squarespace only supports CSS. So when I pasted in the [class... code it swapped the order on desktop rather than mobile. and when I pasted in the other code it made no difference.

Comment: Yes this worked!!! Thank you thank you thank you! There's two (small) problems though 1) it only did it to the first 2 blocks 2) The code applied to the whole website, and has messed up some of the pages, can the code be applied only to that specific page please? Thank you!

Comment: Thumbs up if it help you ;)

Comment: SORRY Renzo, I pressed send by accident. The code worked but has a few issues, could you still have a look at them please? I edited my answer above 'There's two (small) problems though 1) it only did it to the first 2 blocks 2) The code applied to the whole website, and has messed up some of the pages, can the code be applied only to that specific page please? Thank you'

Comment: The code is updated this will prevent the code being applied to the whole site, for your first bug I'll recomend access to the html using [flexbox order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/order), but for that you might need to add at least some extra class in number 3 and 4 containers....only those are affected..

Comment: Renzo, I just fixed the issue with the numbers, they are all fine now (the text boxes merged by accident). However I still cannot find a way to make it apply only to this page :S I'm so sorry to be a pain! But we're so close now :D

Comment: Try adding the new code I just updated hope it help nice work btw...you can check [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) that will help you to affect only a desired section

Comment: Yayyyy! Thank you so much! It's worked! You're amazing! You have no idea how long I've been trying to do this !  Actually the code without my unique ID worked. (Sorry my fault) because I needed to paste the code into the specific page rather than the one for the whole website! So this one: 

@media  (max-width: 600px) {
    .sqs-row{
      display: flex !important;

      flex-direction: column-reverse !important;
    }

}

Thank you so much again!!! ☺️

Comment: Nice work! Marked as the correct answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

Simona, try this out! Tell me what you think!

http://jsfiddle.net/rickydam/m46de34a/2/

I can modify this code to work with your website if you want!

This is the most important code from that example.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .rowname {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey Ricky! Thank you, but it didn't work. The last bit of code from RenzoCC seemed to have work, but now has a few issues.